# find distinct R_ID from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

```
Create table Client_Registration
(
    Client_ID int,
    Rad_ID int 
);

INSERT INTO Client_Registration (Client_ID,Rad_ID)
VALUES ('1','1');
INSERT INTO Client_Registration (Client_ID,Rad_ID)
VALUES ('2','1');
INSERT INTO Client_Registration (Client_ID,Rad_ID)
VALUES ('3','2');
INSERT INTO Client_Registration (Client_ID,Rad_ID)
VALUES ('4','2');
INSERT INTO Client_Registration (Client_ID,Rad_ID)
VALUES ('1','1');

select client_id,distinct Rad_ID from Client_registration
ORDER BY client_id, Rad_ID;
```

I have to find distinct R_ID from table

Comment: So what is the problem? select distinct Rad_ID from Client_registration

Comment: i want client and rad distinct

Comment: select distinct client_id,Rad_ID from Client_registration will return you 4 rows. Isn't it what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about aggregating the column `client_ID` using `MAX()` or `MIN()`?

```
SELECT MAX(client_id) client_id, Rad_ID
FROM   Client_registration
GROUP  BY Rad_ID
ORDER  BY client_id, Rad_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0e42/19)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
SELECT DISTINCT client_id, Rad_ID
FROM Client_registration
ORDER BY client_id, Rad_ID
```

Note that there's no semicolon. SQL Server does not need semicolons.

Comment: i want clientID and radID distinct

Comment: Can you please post a sample expected output?